# Laravel Horizon queue keeps pausing for one minute

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord, pusher

**TL;DR** Laravel Horizon queue workers go to sleep for 60 seconds after each job they process

I have a big backlog in my Laravel Horizon queue. There are a lot of workers (maxProcesses set to 30), but when I monitor the log file, the output suggests that it is processing exactly 30 jobs over the course of 2-3 seconds, and then it pauses for a full minute (more or less exactly 60 seconds).

Any ideas why this could be happening? Am I hitting some resource limit that is causing Horizon or Supervisor to hit the breaks?

Here's the relevant section from my horizon.php config file:

```php
'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['high', 'default', 'low'],
                'balance' => 'false',
                'minProcesses' => 3,
                'maxProcesses' => 30,
                'timeout' => 1800,
                'tries' => 3
            ],
```

I have the exact same configuration in my local environment, and my throughput locally is ~600 jobs/minute. In production it hovers right around ~30 jobs/minute.

**Update per @Qumber's request**

For the most part these aren't actually jobs. They're events being handled by one or more listeners, most of which are super simple. For example:

```php
public function handle(TransactionDeleted $event)
{
    TransactionFile::where("transaction_id", $event->subject->id)->delete();
}
```

Here's some queue config:

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
    'retry_after' => 1900,
    'block_for' => null,
],
```

**Update per @sykez request**

Here's the supervisor config in *local*:

```
[program:laravelqueue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path/to/artisan queue:once redis --sleep=1 --tries=1

autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=adam
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Here's the supervisor config in *production*:

```
[program:daemon-XXXXXX]
directory=/home/forge/SITE_URL/current/
command=php artisan horizon

process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/.forge/daemon-XXXXXX.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

The local supervisor is running the queue directly, with the "once" flag, which should load the entire code base for each job rather than running as a daemon. This, of course, should make it slower, not 20 times faster...

**Another update**
Thanks to some help from one of the core Laravel devs, we were able to determine that all of the "hanging" jobs were broadcast jobs, from events that were configured to broadcast after firing. We use Pusher as our broadcast engine. When Pusher is disabled (as it is in our local environment), then the jobs finish immediately with no pause.

Comment: Could you also post the `handle` function of the job and your `queue.php` config file, please?

Comment: Hiya - are you sure your jobs are correctly terminated?  Perhaps they keep running for 30 seconds and you didn't notice?  Perhaps you can log start and end time of any queued job?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are correctly terminated. The log shows "Processed XYZJob", which I don't believe it would output until the job had finished successfully.

Comment: Could you share your supervisor configurations as well, for both local and production?

Comment: I noticed that my answer may not cut it. Can you check `top` / `htop` if you get only one horizon process?

Comment: @Kyslik No, there are lots of horizon processes (30), each one reading /usr/bin/php7.4 artisan horizon:work redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=high,default,low --sleep=3 --timeout=1800 --tries=3 --supervisor=XXXXXX:supervisor-1

Comment: I've a feeling this could be a resource related issue. I've got a couple of questions :) What's your server spec? How's the CPU usage while the jobs are running? Have you tried lowering the number, perhaps 5 or 10? Are any of your jobs failing or retried? Whats the average/max runtime on your jobs? Any reason you're not using balanced? Where is your redis hosted?

Comment: @sykez, I've reduced the number of queue workers to as few as 3, and the problem still occurs. None of the jobs fail; they just hang for 60 seconds.

Comment: @AdamTheHutt What was the solution? I'm suddenly seeing JOBS PER MINUTE
1 too. It's way too slow. My CPU usage is 100%. And these are simple Mailcoach jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960482/470749 Thanks.

Comment: @sykez Thanks for your comments above. I'd LOVE if you could please look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960482/470749 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with queues suddenly waiting up to a minute before starting the next job, even on multiple threads, but for me there was little correlation between the jobs that would trigger it (and it was often the same ones, but not always).

I ended up resolving it by increasing the memory limit in config/horizon.php from 64 to 128mb:

```
'defaults' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'memory' => 128,
    ],
],
```

This setting was added to the default config sometime in Horizon v5, at 128MB, but on the system I was working on it had already been set at 64MB, causing this issue to appear way down the line.