# Laravel Horizon is slow (1 job per minute) processing mailcoach-feedback on Redis

Tags: laravel, redis

I have [Mailcoach 2](https://mailcoach.app/docs/v2/package/general/installation-and-setup#install-horizon) on Laravel.

I'm using a $5/mo Digital Ocean server with 1 vCPU and 1 GB RAM.

But I think it has processed these sames jobs *many times faster* in the past.

I've tried restarting Supervisor / Horizon.

I've tried increasing the number of processes allocated to the mailcoach-feedback queue to 10.

CPU usage seems to be at 100%, and RAM usage is around 80%.

What should I look into as to why this is so slow now? Thanks.

P.S. `ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | grep timeout` shows a bunch of lines like:

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 artisan horizon:work redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=default --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --supervisor=ubuntu-s-1vcpu
/usr/bin/php7.4 artisan horizon:work mailcoach-redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=mailcoach-feedback --sleep=3 --timeout=600 --tries=1 --supervisor=ubuntu-s-1vcpu
```

UPDATE:

I then ran in MySQL: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` which led me to see that

```
SELECT 
    MIN(`id`) AS aggregate
FROM
    `webhook_calls`
WHERE
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`payload`, '$."MessageId"'))
```

is taking ~13 seconds each time.

So maybe Mailcoach wasn't designed very well (or I set it up wrong)?

If you have ideas about what to explore from here or how to fix, I'd appreciate them.

Comment: did you check if other processes may cause the high load? You can use something like `htop`

Comment: @MaartenDev I appreciate your response. Great point! `htop` shows 98% CPU used by `/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize`. And then there are 37 other processes with that same command too. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/270810/18098 and https://superuser.com/a/1552877/74576 seem to suggest it's normal to have a bunch of processes.  I will update the question with something else I just noticed. Thanks.

Comment: 1gb for MySql may be the limiting factor, could you try hosting the database on another server?

Comment: @MaartenDev Even though RAM usage is only 80%? I'd think the RAM therefore isn't the limiting factor. I'm not experienced with JSON in MySQL, but doesn't it seem like maybe the problem relates to poor indexing? `SHOW INDEX FROM webhook_calls;` only shows the primary key. Thanks.

Comment: You could try changing mysql settings like how big the buffer is to check if that impacts the performance? It is hard to say without knowing the amount of data in the database.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE webhook_calls; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'webhook_calls'; and D) htop output, please for analysis.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Looking at your server spec and your CPU being at 100%, that doesn't sound good at all. So I'm guessing you've nginx, php, mysql, redis, and horizon running on the same server? Seems like MySQL is struggling for resources. Increasing your Horizon worker process probably would made things worse at this point. How is your overall query performance throughout your app besides the jobs? You can use Debugbar or Telescope for this. Like MaartenDevn mentioned, you can try moving MySQL to another server, or temporarily upgrade your server spec (try 4 core 8G) to see if it improves.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I appreciate your willingness to help. I was going to take you up on it but decided to try to upgrade stuff first yesterday, which I did. As I posted in an answer, I don't see the problem anymore. Thanks.

Comment: @sykez Thanks for your comment! Luckily, as I posted in an answer just now, I don't see the problem anymore. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan Congratulations on pursuing your situation and arriving at a satisfactory resolution with the upgrade activities you completed.  We are here, if you need to get in touch.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not diagnosed the root cause of the problem, I figured people would appreciate knowing that the problem isn't happening anymore.

I upgraded from PHP 7 to PHP 8, Laravel 7 to Laravel 8, and Mailcoach 2 to Mailcoach 4.

Maybe those upgrades (or other upgrades that were required alongside them) "solved" the problem in some way.